# How to add an arrow and explanation to parts of an equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

related to [How to add an arrow and explanation to each term in an equation in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15695/how-to-add-an-arrow-and-explanation-to-each-term-in-an-equation-in-beamer) and [Adding arrows to each term of an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15735/adding-arrows-to-each-term-of-an-equation)

is there an equivalent version without beamer for parts of an equation not terms?

I am thinking

```
\[ \arrowannotate{dependent var1}{y} =
   \frac{1+\arrowannotate{independent var1}{x}{2} + \arrowannotate{independent var2}{z} \]
```

It is not important whether the location of the annotation is automatic or requires userspecification.  That is, maybe

```
\arrowannotate{dependent var1}{-2}{1}{y}
```

would be just as good.  of course, I already know that the answer will entail tikz, but tikz is an art.  and I need an artist!

;-)

Comment: All of your links are for ps-tricks.  Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302517/using-tikzmark-subnode-with-overlays-beamer and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281121/arrows-from-equation-causing-equation-to-look-untidy instead.